# Parameterize Performance Build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

I am new to jenkins. I am trying to moniter performance test for my project.
I have my scripts in Jmeter.

I have created paarmeterize job in jenkins as shown.
Threads: 1
RampUp: 1
Loop: 40.

I am using backend listner to check data in Grafana and Appdynamics.
Now when i start the build the scripts run only once, but i am expecting script must run for 40 times (With build success).
But when i run it through jmeter, scripts run for 40 times succesfully. (Some issue with jenkins i suppose)

Please suggest how can i resolve the issue in jenkins as my project requeiremnt needs it to run script from jenkins.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing your Jenkins job and JMeter [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration.

In order to apply external settings in JMeter you need to define threads, ramp-up and the number of iterations using JMeter Properties via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

[image]

Once done you will be able to [override the values of these properties using `-J` command line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override), for example in Jenkins:

```
jmeter -Jthreads=1 -Jrampup=1 -Jloops=40 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

[image]

This way you will be able to pass whatever number of virtual users/iterations without having to change your script.

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)